# how to install Spark and Hadoop from tarball separately [Cloudera]

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, spark-streaming

I want to install Cloudera distribution of Hadoop and Spark using tarball.
I have already set up Hadoop in Pseudo-Distributed mode in my local machine and successfully ran a Yarn example.

I have downloaded latest tarballs CDH 5.3.x from [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_vd_cdh_package_tarball.html)

But the folder structure of Spark downloaded from Cloudera is differrent from Apache website. This may be because Cloudera provides it's own version maintained separately.

So, as there are no documentation I have found yet to install Spark from this Cloudera's tarball separately. 
Could someone help me to understand how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Spark could be extracted to any directory. You just need to run the `./bin/spark-submit` command (available in extracted spark directory) with required parameters to submit the job. To start spark interactive shell, please use command `./bin/spark-shell`.

Comment: Got this error while running `./bin/spark-shell`
ls: cannot access /.../spark-1.2.0-cdh5.3.2/assembly/target/scala-2.10: No such file or directory
Failed to find Spark assembly in /.../spark-1.2.0-cdh5.3.2/assembly/target/scala-2.10
You need to build Spark before running this program.

Comment: It seems this tarball does not contain all the dependencies for spark. If you create a dummy file RELEASE in spark dir and move .jar files from spark folder to ./lib/, then the error you are facing will disappear but you will face another error ` java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. If RELEASE file is not there, it assumes it needs to build spark-assembly. I have downloaded Spark from Apache website, I am able to use it without problems on HDP 2.2 Sandbox. Also this spark assembly jar file is bigger that CDH tarball jar and seemed to contain all the dependencies.

Comment: yeah, I have used Spark from Apache website but I could not understand one downloaded from Cloudera. And there are no documentation for build